# Knex: Rollback specific migration?

Tags: express, knex.js

I'd like to be able to rollback a specific `knex` migration on the command line.

For example:

```
knex migrate:rollback('20161104101325')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**From the doc:**

To undo the specified migration that was run

```bash
knex migrate:down 001_migration_name.js
```

To run the specified migration that has not yet been run

```bash
knex migrate:up 001_migration_name.js
```

To list both completed and pending migrations:

```bash
knex migrate:list
```

(to list and check)

(`migrate:list` was released in 0.19.3! if not available update knex (`npm i -g knex`))

Answer (score 9):

Update: This answer is now out of date - the functionality was since implemented in knex as stated by mcating comment and by Mohamed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926479/98810)

At this point of time this is not possible - you can find the discussion of this feature in this GitHub ticket: [#666](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/666)

You can use [knex-migrate](https://github.com/sheerun/knex-migrate) which is a migration toolkit for knex and supports the `--only` flag for rollbacks.

Comment: A knex migrate:down capability was added around May 28, 2019. See https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/666.